# How to view/monitor live database connections in a database pool?

Tags: java, database, tomcat, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

We use database connection pooling for our java application. It is a web app run under tomcat.

I want to view live connections in the pool as they are created and destroyed. Can somebody please help?

UPDATE: We are using Oracle 11g. We use DDConnectionBroker library for connection pooling.

Comment: Hi user32262 did you solve your problem? I need the same information. Start to dig on stackoverflow but no success.

Comment: Do you want to monitor the number of threads that are waiting for a connection to become available? If yes, a DDConnectionBroker-specific tool is needed.

Comment: @user32262 Did you mean "DbConnectionBroker"? at http://javaexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there are any connection monitoring API's in DDConnectionBroker library... I would recommend Proxool if you want more transparency.

http://proxool.sourceforge.net/

Also check out DBCP and CP30, DBCP is the best in the bucket

http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Database/Connection-Pool.htm

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this issue too and could collect what I need from:

> [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.2.2/index.html)

If you are using **Spring** is so easy to inject this information on your bean and retreive what you need from this object, that shall came injected and already instantiated for you.

[Any questions let me know!](http://mailto%3arafa.ferreira@gmail.com)

Comment: The question is about DbConnectionBroker, not Commons DBCP.